# Couchbase N1QL Query - Include outer document as parent

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am new to Couchbase so need a little help in below n1ql query:

```
company:1
{
  'companyName':'A',
  'employees':[{
     'empId':101,
     'name':'Test',
     'deptId':'dept:1'
   },
   {
     'empId':102,
     'name':'Test2',
     'deptId':'dept:1'
   }]
}

dept:1
{
 'deptName':'Dept One',
 'location':'First Floor'
}
```

Output I need is like :

```
 company:1
    {
      'companyName':'A',
      'departments':[{
         'deptName':'Dept One',
         'location':'First Floor'
         'employees:[{
            'empId':101,
            'name':'Test',
            'deptId':'dept:1'
           },
           {
            'empId':102,
            'name':'Test2',
            'deptId':'dept:1'
           }]
       }],          
    }
```

I tried using Unnest and then using sub query but could not achieve the desired result. May be NEST can help but I dont have much idea, how to use NEST in n1ql.

Please help to achive the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you unnest the employees and then group by company, department.
Second you do group by company

```
SELECT d1.companyName, ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_ADD(dep,"employees", d1.employees)) AS departments
FROM ( SELECT d.companyName, e.deptId, ARRAY_AGG(e) AS employees
       FROM default AS d
       UNNEST d.employees AS e
       WHERE d.type = "company"
       GROUP BY d.companyName, e.deptId) AS d1
LET dep = (SELECT RAW d3 FROM default AS d3 USE KEYS d1.deptId)[0]
GROUP BY d1.companyName;
```